# Battery charging / discharging in a very challenging temperature environment

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, temperature, charging

I'm searching for a solution to charge and discharge a battery pack. The current idea is to use 18650 cells, with 4 or 6 cells (~25-60 Wh) in series. The outside environment I'm dealing with can be between -40 and up to +55 degree C. The average temperature in the sub zero temperature window might be in the range of -15 degree C but might drop down to -40 degree in a worst case scenario. The cell manufacturer is not chosen yet, but what I've seen is that there are hardly any manufacturers, with Li-Ion cells operateable below -20 degree C due to technological limits.

The battery pack will be mounted inside a metal housing (~2-3 mm wall thickness) and in there be placed in a plastic case as well. Space inside the housing is very limited and a 6-cell series 18650 battery pack is already pushing that constraint. The battery works as a backup energy provider that may power a system up to 20 min. The battery will be used regularly but not regulary for the full 20 min - more to buffer short power losses in between. The system may consume roughly around 2-3 W. The aim is to never use the battery pack to its full potential and never use it below 50 % SoC. Most of the time the battery should topped of by a charging unit at a low charging rate (~ 0.1 C).

What I've gathered so far is that Li-Ions energy capacity will drastically drop of below zero degree celsius. Since it is not planed to use its full capacity anyways, I guess the major problem I'm facing is charging at low temperatures as this might even kill the battery. Since the battery should be always be topped off. An itendend lifespan of a battery pack should be in the range of 8 years.

I'll try to measure the temperature drop-off at the extrem temperatures inside the housing to get a feeling what I'm dealing with in detail. Additionally I think that the battery will not heat itself due to very low power consumption of the system.

1. Are there better battery- or energy-storage-technologies out there with an equal packaging format, energy density and cost spectrum that i might have overlooked?
2. Is charging Li-Ion batteries at sub zero degrees possible for the proposed 8 year battery-usage?
3. Would charging with the intendent low charging-rate be beneficial at low temperatures to reduce wear on the cells?
4. Is thermically isolating the battery-package an idea to protect it from the temperature-extremes?

Thanks in advance and best regards!

Comment: You may find this discussion useful. https://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/charging_at_high_and_low_temperatures#:~:text=Li%20ion%20can%20be%20fast,diffusion%20rates%20on%20the%20anode.